# datepicker value is getting clear when addon button is clicked

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, eonasdan-datetimepicker

[image]Here is code used in simpleschema definition.I tried to use the similar one in my project but as you can see it is not working.

```
{ 
  items:{ 
    type: Array, 
    optional: true,
    minCount: 0,
    maxCount: 5 
  }, 
  "items.$": {
    type: Object, 
    optional: true
  },
  "items.$.name": {
    type: Date,
    optional: true, 
    autoform: {
      afFieldInput: { 
        type: "bootstrap-datetimepicker" 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the issue because of some bug in `autoform-datetimepicker` Api.

I added the following line of code under `autoform-bs-datepicker.js`

`

```
this.autorun(function () {
var data = Template.currentData(); 

**if(!data.value)      
  data.value=$('#'+data.atts.id).val();**`
```